# How to force LLVM -loop-unroll optimization?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I have a basic IR saved into `fact.ll` file:

```
define i32 @factorial(i32 %val) {
entry:
  %i = add i32 0, 2
  %temp = add i32 0, 1
  br label %check_for_condition

check_for_condition:
  %i_leq_val = icmp sle i32 %i, %val
  br i1 %i_leq_val, label %for_body, label %end_loop 

for_body:
  %new_temp = mul i32 %temp, %i 
  %i_plus_one = add i32 %i, 1 
  br label %check_for_condition

end_loop:
  ret i32 %temp
}
```

This is a representation of iterative factorial function.

How do I use LLVM tools in order to convert this IR into an optimized one? I tried this command to get an IR with the loop unrolled:

```
opt -loop-unroll fact.ll -S
```

But the command above prints pretty much the same IR code. I've tried adding different flags like `-unroll-count`, but this doesn't make any difference.

Is my understanding of loop unrolling optimization in LLVM wrong, and this step only happens in C++ frontend?

Comment: Opt can run the unroller. But you're assuming that unroller is a win even when the loop body will fit in one cache line like that, which I'd be surprised if the unroller assumes. BTW, you can see what passes are run using e.g. `opt -time-passes` and and what each pass does using `opt -print-after-all` or just `opt -print-after=loop-unroll`.

Comment: I suggest you to add to your opt flags "-debug". This should tell you if something is failing in the optimization you are trying to run.

Comment: I have noticed a similar problem. The only way I found to force unroll, is to insert `#pragma unroll(<put unrolling factor here>)` in the C source code before the for loop